# Validate list item in REST

Tags: javascript, rest, sharepoint-2013

I have a function that will add list item using REST. But I want to validate a list item if its already exist on my list first before I add it. How will do it?

```
function addListItem() {    

var title = $("#txtTitle").val();
var siteUrl = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl;
var fullUrl = siteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('Employee')/items";

$.ajax({
    url: fullUrl,
    type: "POST",
    data: JSON.stringify({
        '__metadata': { 'type': 'SP.Data.EmployeeListItem' },   
        'EmployeeID': $("#txtEmpID").val(),
        'Name': $("#txtName").val(),

    }),
    headers: {
        "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
        "content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
        "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()
    },
    success: onQuerySucceeded,
    error: onQueryFailed
});

function onQuerySucceeded(sender, args) {
alert("Item successfully added!");
}

  function onQueryFailed() {
  alert('Error!');
}

 };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the  [OData query operations in SharePoint REST requests](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp142385.aspx#sectionSection1) 
use the [$filter](http://www.odata.org/documentation/odata-version-2-0/uri-conventions/#FilterSystemQueryOption) parameter in a Get operation to validate if the user exists in the list, using something like this:

```
$filter=Name eq '<UserName>'
```

An example:

```
 siteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('Employee')/items?$filter=Name eq 'John'
```

> < UserName > is the textbox value

You can see a Response sample here:

http://services.odata.org/Northwind/Northwind.svc/Customers?$filter=ContactName%20eq%20%27Maria%20Anders%27

Just do a Get request and count the elements to know if the user exists

```
$.get("/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Employee')/items?$filter=Name eq '<Name>'",function(e){
    if($(e).find("entry").length > 0){
          console.log("user exists");
    }

})
```

You can see a Complete basic operations using SharePoint 2013 REST endpoints using JQuery/Javascript here:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj164022.aspx

Comment: Hi Kamus can you show me the code on how to count the elements? Sorry quite new with REST.